# Extracting table data in SQL Server 2008 to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, vb6

I have a table in my SQL Server 2008 with client data. Something very simple, just FirstName, LastName, Sex, MI. What I've been trying to do it extract it to Excel but when I try to do it, it gets extracted as a text file. Basically the text is in one cell and looks like a mess. What is wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub cmdExtract_CLick()
    Dim filenum as Integer
    Dim vSQL as String
    Dim cndX as Adodb.Recordset

    filenum=freefile
    dim theFilename as string
    theFIlename ="C:\Test\TestFile.CSV"

    Open theFilename for Output as #filenum
    Write #filenum, "First, Last, MI, SEX"

    vSQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Sex, MI from dbo.Test_Clients2"
    cnd.open, vSQL

    set cndx =New Adodb.Recordset
    cndx.move first

    Do while no cndx.eof
    write #filenum, cndx("FirstName") & "," & cndx("LastName") & "," & cndx(Sex)   & "'" & cndx("MI"
    loop

    cndx.close
    cnd.close
    close #filenum
End Sub
```

So this is what I have. NOt sure where I'm making the mistake, but I am probably missing something. The data loads fine into the excel sheet, but is all in one cell.

Comment: `Write` vs `Print` ?

Comment: Why are you writing a CSV file at all? If you are looking to get the data into Excel use the [Range.CopyFromRecordset method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx). Your code is broken and even incomplete in places.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the [Power Query add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379) from Microsoft. It's probably more effective than using vba for importing data from a SQL database.

Here for example:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("Servername", "DBname", [Query="SELECT FirstName, LastName, Sex, MI from dbo.Test_Clients2"])
in
    Source
```

You can of course extract your data from a csv-file in the same way.